# How to get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationIdentity TFS API 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to make a utility for working with TFS and I get owner value from testcase and want to change it:

```
var gss = Connection.ProjectCollection.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
Identity validUserSids = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Team Foundation Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);
Identity[] validUsers = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, validUserSids.Members, QueryMembership.None);
var owner = validUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && AccountName == "MyAccountName");
```

But when I trying set `owner` in `testCase.Owner` I get an error: `Cannot conver type "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Identity" to type "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationIdentity"`, cast also gives an error.

How can I get `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationIdentity` collection to set the value in the field `testCase.Owner`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ITestBase.Owner Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestbase.owner.aspx) in 
[ITestCase Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestcase.aspx)

```
TeamFoundationIdentity Owner { get; set; }
```

Such as below code:

```
  public static ITestCase CreateTestCase(ITestManagementTeamProject project, string title, string desc = "", TeamFoundationIdentity owner = null)
    {
        // Create a test case.
        ITestCase testCase = project.TestCases.Create();
        testCase.Owner = owner;
        testCase.Title = title;
        testCase.Description = desc;
        testCase.Save();
        return testCase;
    }
```

More detail info you can refer this blog [Manage TFS Test Cases C# Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878584/Manage-TFS-Test-Cases-Csharp-Code).